# Bathroom Drainage/Vent Layout

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain-waste-vent, venting

So I've been doing a full remodel of our bathroom given water damage from the last owners. I've gone down to the joists & studs. Now I'm looking at drainage/venting solutions. I've got a few plumbers coming by in the next few weeks, but wanted to get a broader range of opinions.

I have a single standard vent of 2" going up through the roof at this point. I'm trying to avoid tearing out the ceiling, as it's the only damn thing in the bathroom that was salvageable. So I started looking into AAV (eeek, not liking what I've been reading) and wet venting.

So I went through and read a ton of code, and tables, and really get lost when they start talking about maximum distances from certain portions of the system to others based on pipe sizes. So here's a rough idea of what I would like to do, but I'm not sure if the piping sizes & distances will be up to code.

**Question**: Do these distances & pipe diameters actually work for this type of wet vent layout?

BTW I live in upstate NY

After doing some more research it seems I might have to move to a 3" wet vent at the very least. Would appreciate some professional input on the matter though.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I'll answer my own question to the best of my knowledge thus far.

The max distances from vent to trap have been clarified for me to mean from wet vent to trap, not just dry vent.

So the ipc code states that the toilet can be anywhere as long as there is a vent because it self syphons. I just have to reroute it so it doesn't drain past the tub downstream, which is also being wet vented.

The distance for the tub is within ipc spec as long as the lav's wet vent portion of ths drain is at least 2" in diameter.